# Invoking a java function from JSP Script tag

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP file as below

```
<SCRIPT>
function validateEvent(){
 // I want to call Java function myProfile() here
 }
 </SCRIPT>

 <html:select property="event" styleClass="input"   onchange="validateEvent();">
  </html:select>
```

All I want to do is, call the java function myProfile() from validateEvent() function, that gets triggered on change of the value in event dropdown. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to use ajax

Comment: JavaScript is executed in the browser, whereas JSP on the server. If you want to invoke  server-side Java from javascript, you will need an XHR ("ajax"/"rest") request.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `<script>` tag to execute a java method server-side from the client. Those tags corresponds to Javascript, which is executed on the client side, and therefore it doesn't have access to what's going on on your server directly.

If you need to retrieve information from your server, have a look at something called AJAX.